# TranslateAnimation in AnimationSet doesn't start from 0 position, why?

Tags: android, animation

I expect the button move down 200px (from 0,0 to 0, 200)
and after 1 second, move up again to original position.

But following code acts like start from (0,200) to (0,400), not start from (0,0)

If I put one animation into AnimationSet, it works fine. But it works strange if I put more than two animations in the AnimationSet.

What's the problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int DISTANCE = 200;
    private static final long DURATION = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        TranslateAnimation aniMove = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, DISTANCE);
        aniMove.setDuration(DURATION);

        TranslateAnimation aniMoveBack = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, DISTANCE, 0); 
        aniMoveBack.setDuration(DURATION);
        aniMoveBack.setStartOffset(DURATION + 1000);

        AnimationSet aniSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        aniSet.addAnimation(aniMove);
        aniSet.addAnimation(aniMoveBack);
        btn.startAnimation(aniSet);
    }
}
```

Here is XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> AnimationSet represents a group of Animations that should be played together. The
>   transformation of each individual animation are composed together into
>   a single transform.

AnimationSet could not be used in this way, it could combine the feature of multi animations. Using AnimationSet you can perform alpha and rotate animation at the same time.

If you want to play 2 animations in order, you should start the second animation in onAnimationEnd() of the first animation.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
Coordinates in TranslateAnimation() parameter is not absolute one.
Because I called setStartOffset(N), aniMoveBack animation will start from the end of aniMove coordinate.
It is relative position.

So, the code should be fixed like this..

```
TranslateAnimation aniMoveBack = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -DISTANCE);
```